# Clock keeps restarting after pause

Tags: javascript

I've made a little bit of code and I'm using it to track playtime. Everytime a user pauses something it will pause the timer. But, when they resume it just restarts the timer. Any help will be useful and I'm happy to provide more info if need be. Thanks!

```
    startClock() {
      this.timeStart = Date.now();
      this.timeItv = setInterval( this.updateClock, 1000 );
      this.updateClock();
    },

    updateClock() {
      let p = n => ( n < 10 ) ? '0'+n : ''+n;
      let elapsed = ( Date.now() - this.timeStart ) / 1000;
      let seconds = Math.floor( elapsed % 60 );
      let minutes = Math.floor( elapsed / 60 % 60 );
      this.timeDisplay = p( minutes ) +':'+ p( seconds );
    },

    stopClock() {
      if ( this.timeItv ) clearInterval( this.timeItv );
      this.timeItv = null;
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting `this.timeStart` every time you click start. One approach is to keep track of elapsed time when you pause it.

I typically don't like to just post solutions but it's a bit complicated to explain exactly what to do in your case and this can be a bit tricky. I've added code that lets you pause and reset the clock. It also has good separation of concerns so that the `Timer` class could easily be used from other contexts.

**Reminder:** This is not the only approach, just one approach.

```js
class Timer {
  get currentTime() {
    if (this.paused) {
      return this.elapsedBeforeLastStart;
    }

    const now = new Date().getTime();
    return this.elapsedBeforeLastStart + (now - this.lastStartTime);
  }

  elapsedBeforeLastStart = 0;
  lastStartTime = 0;
  paused = true;

  start() {
    if (!this.paused) {
      return;
    }
    this.paused = false;
    this.lastStartTime = new Date().getTime();
  }

  pause() {
    this.elapsedBeforeLastStart = this.currentTime;
    this.paused = true;
  }

  reset() {
    this.paused = true;
    this.elapsedBeforeLastStart = 0;
  }
}

const timer = new Timer();

function paint() {
  document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = String(timer.currentTime);
  requestAnimationFrame(paint);
}
requestAnimationFrame(paint);

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
buttons[0].addEventListener("click", () => timer.start());
buttons[1].addEventListener("click", () => timer.pause());
buttons[2].addEventListener("click", () => timer.reset());
```

```html
<div id="app">0 ms</div>

<button>Start</button>
<button>Pause</button>
<button>Reset</button>
```

And here's a simplified version of the above `Timer` (in TypeScript) which combines `lastStartTime` and `paused` into one variable:

```
class Timer {
  get currentTime(): number {
    if (!this.startedAt) {
      return this.timeElapsed;
    }
    return this.timeElapsed += (Date.now() - this.startedAt);
  }
  private startedAt = 0;
  private timeElapsed = 0;
  start() {
    if (this.startedAt) {
      return;
    }
    this.startedAt = Date.now();
  }
  pause() {
    this.startedAt = undefined;
  }
}
```